# Prepend http:// to a url field if it's not already there

Tags: fields

I have a field that contains a url. This url is sent to marketing cloud and the link only works if is prepended with "https://", how can i automatically add this if a user only enters "www.google.com"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1

Create an additional **Formula** Field of type Text, with the formula being to concatenate 'https://' and your field which holds the URL.

I created an example of a **URL** data type field which I called *Web Link*, and then a **Formula** field which I called *Web Link Formula from URL Field*.  Here is the creationg of the *Formula* field:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here are the results in the UI:
[image]

*NOTE: both are clickable links*

You would not necessarily have to make your **Formula** field visible, and even if hidden you could just send the value of your **Formula** field to your marketing cloud.

---

*EDIT*

In order to not repeat the `https://` in the case that a user enters it, you could wrap the formula in an `IF` with a `BEGINS`:

```
IF( BEGINS(Web_Link__c, 'https://') , Web_Link__c, 'https://' & Web_Link__c)
```

HOWEVER this is putting a lot of trust that the user will correctly enter the "https://".

And please note that this would only cover the case that a user entered "https://".  Obviously the user could enter something invalid (like "https:") and you would end up with `https://https:salesforce.stackexchange.com`.

---

#### Option 2

(Which I think is better)

You could put a **Validation Rule** on your original field to either

- A. Make the user enter "https://"

**OR**

- B. Not allow the user to enter "https://"

(You would select the option depending on your expectations of and relationship with your users.)

**Option 2A: Make the user enter "https://"**

Your validation rule would look like this:
`NOT(BEGINS(Web_Link__c, 'https://'))`

Here it is in action:
[image]

And here I was able to save after adding "https://":
[image]

*NOTE: If you use this option, you would NOT need a separate **Formula** field.

**Option 2B: Not allow the user to enter "https://"**

Your validation rule would look something like this:
`BEGINS(Web_Link__c, 'http')`

Using `http` should cover almost everything a user might enter (e.g., "http:", "https://").

Here it is in action:
[image]

And here I was able to save after removing "https://":
[image]

*NOTE: If you use this option, you WOULD REQUIRE a separate **Formula** field as originally noted in **Option 1**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! however, it doesn't look like this way would take into account whether a user has added http by themselves and so this formula would then add http again?

Comment: Hello ollieF - you could extend the above formula field to include a check the first characters of the string - You could use LEFT(TEXTFIELD__c, 5) to check if TEXTFIELD__c starts with HTTPS, then use an IF statement to either add HTTPS or not add it.

Comment: @ollieF : You are correct.  I edited and appended my answer.

Comment: Thank you v much!!